# Ubuntu with SQL Server error with AD Authentication

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem to connect my SQL Server 2017 on Ubuntu server 16.04 with the active directory located on a Win Server 2012 essential.

I always got this error : I'm specifying my server, select Windows Authentification, then :Login failed. The login is from an untrusted demoain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

I've checked for hours to fix this issue and still nothing.
Here's the step I followed:

1. Ubuntu Installation basic with samba, standard system utilities
   and OpenSSH server
2. SQL Server 2017 express installation : I followed the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu)
3. I joined my company domain : I followed the guide [here](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/ubuntu-join-a-server-to-an-active-directory-domain)
4. I tried to link SQL Server to the Active directory : I followed the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication)

If you need more information, I can provide krb5.conf, smb.conf, etc. files

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem ...  oufffff after hours of research to find out that I had to add another SPN with only the servername and port

Like setspn -A MSSQLSvb/**SQL-SERVER_NAME**:1433 **accountServiceName**

So I added this one with the other with the fqdn...

Hope this will help someone, one day!!!